# trouble getting javascript global variable in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, global-variables

I have checked all the other 'duplicate' questions on this. But have hit a wall in terms of finding what is wrong with my script. Could be something very simple. But I have run out of steam finding the fault. So I am here.

I am trying to create a product list on a web page with an 'Inquire' link for each product. On clicking the link, the product id is captured and a brief form for adding user contact details comes up. When the user submits the form, the inquired product details and user contact details are emailed to admin.

I am doing all this with JS with an Ajax Post call to a PHP file.

Everything is fine accept between the two functions

1. When 'Inquire' link is clicked 
   and
2. When form submit button is clicked.

My issue is, I am not able to pass the inquired product name variable 'item' to the submit function. In submit function I get 'item' undefined.

I am not too good at JS. I know I am making some procedural error. Would be great if somebody could point out what I am doing wrong.

My codes;

HTML

```
<div class="prodlist"><div class="productimg"><h4 id="itemcf">Cupellation Furnace</h4><img src="images/cupellation-furnace.png" alt="cupellation furnace"></div><div class="prodtxt"> This is the product description area. This area will contain details and specifications</div><div id="inquirecf"><span>Inquire</span></div><div id="inqrescf"></div></div>
<div class="prodlist"><div class="productimg"><h4 id="itemmf">Melting Furnace</h4><img src="images/furnace-2kg.png" alt="Melting furnace"></div><div class="prodtxt"> This is the product description area. This area will contain details and specifications</div><div id="inquiremf"><span>Inquire</span></div><div id="inqresmf"></div></div>
<div id="inqform">
<span id="inqclose">Close</span>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="inqresgen"></div>
    <form id="forminq" method="post">
        Name  : <input type="text" id="inqname" require><br>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        phone  : <input type="number" id="inqphone" require><br>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        Email  : <input type="email" id="inqemail" require><br>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        Location  : <input type="text" id="inqloc" require><br>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        Message : <textarea cols="30" rows="10" id="inqmsg" require></textarea>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <input type="submit" onClick="sendInq();" value="Send">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </form>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var item;

$('#inqclose').click(function(){ $('#inqform').fadeOut('fast');});

$('#inquirecf,#inquiremf').click(function(){ 

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
//alert(id);
    if(id=="inquirecf"){alert("inquirecf"); item="Cupellation Furnace";}
    else if(id=="inquiremf"){alert("inquiremf");item="Melting Furnace";}
    else{alert("No Choices");}
    $('#inqform').slideToggle('fast');

});

});
function sendInq(item){
    var itemv=item;
    event.preventDefault();
    var inqname=$('#inqname').val();
    var inqphone=$('#inqphone').val();
    var inqemail=$('#inqemail').val();
    var inqloc=$('#inqloc').val();
    var inqmsg=$('#inqmsg').val();
    alert("Item : "+ itemv);

    $.post("inquire.php",
        {
          itemname: itemv,
          inqname: inqname,
          inqphone: inqphone,
          inqemail: inqemail,
          inqloc: inqloc,
          inqmsg: inqmsg
        },
        function(data,status){
  //        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);

            $('#inqresgen').html( data );
            ///$('#inqres2').html( "<h4>Inquiry Sent</h4>");

            $('#forminq').fadeOut('fast');

        });
 }
```

Comment: You are not passing the argument to `onClick="sendInq();"`

Comment: It is there in the input type submit in html

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of googling and studying different options, I realized that the using

> window.item

Helped

Now my code looks like

```
$('#inquirecf,#inquiremfhalfkg,#inquiremf1kg,#inquiremf2kg,
#inquiremf5kg,#inquirecupels,#inquiremuffles,#inquirecrucibles,#inquirethermo,
#inquiresilicon').click(function(){ 

var id = $(this).attr('id');

if(id=="inquirecf"){window.item="Cupellation Furnace";}
else if(id=="inquiremfhalfkg"){window.item="Melting Furnace 0.5Kg";}
else if(id=="inquiremf1kg"){window.item="Melting Furnace 1Kg";} 
else if(id=="inquiremf2kg"){window.item="Melting Furnace 2Kg";}
else if(id=="inquiremf5kg"){window.item="Melting Furnace 5Kg";}
else if(id=="inquirecupels"){window.item="Cupels";}
else if(id=="inquiremuffles"){window.item="Muffles";}
else if(id=="inquirecrucibles"){window.item="Crucibles";}
else if(id=="inquirethermo"){window.item="Thermocouples";}
else if(id=="inquiresilicon"){window.item="Silicon Carbide Elements";}  
else{alert("No Choices");}
}

function sendInq(item){
    var itemv=window.item;
//......
}
```

All is well now. Thanks all for your efforts.